# Google Maps — How To Finesse The Viewport Of A Geocoded Address

Tags: maps, google-geocoding-api

I'm implementing Google Maps into a new project and one page should return a large (100% * 100%) map of Canada. I'm also using Geocoding to determine the latlng to be passed to the map.

Here's the code:

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.775, -122.4183333);
        var myOptions ={
            zoom: 5,
            center: myLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        }

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        var address = "Canada";
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(address);
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                //map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                            //The above was too far north
                map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
                map.setZoom(5);
            } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
        });
```

It's working nicely except it's "a little too far to the left". Essentially, it's cut off most of the Maritime provinces. An example can be seen here:

http://50.28.69.176/~sequoia/locations.php

Anyone know how to finesse this so that the country is better centered in the viewport?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of geocoding every time the page is loaded, I'd suggest just getting the correct `LatLng` that you want, and storing it.

If you still want to stick with this approach, you can use the `getCenter()` method on a `LatLngBounds` to get its center.

That way, you can call

```
map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport.getCenter())
map.setZoom(5)
```